# Big capacitor on amplifier output

Tags: amplifier, audio

I am currently making an audio amplifier and I was wondering what is the use of the capacitor C5. I think it's here to avoid having DC voltage in the speakers when switching on the amplifier but, I'm not sure. If anyone could let me know on this, that would be great.

[image: amplifier schematic]

Comment: NB: note that for "some" high power amplifiers, speakers should be (protection needed) "short-circuited" to avoid the initial "step-on" (big clap) charging current of capacitor ... if there is no dedicated circuit for "power-on".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the capacitor C5 is required to block DC from the amplifier.

There is DC because it is a single-supply amplifier, so the amplifier input and output are biased to half-supply voltage. If the supply is 20V, the amplifier input and output idle at 10V.

The value needs to be large to allow low enough frequencies to pass, for example 2200 uF allows 18 Hz to 4 ohm speaker.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Does this capacitor have to be bigger if we have higher supply voltage ?

Comment: No, supply voltage has nothing to do with capacitance. The capacitor voltage rating needs to be enough so that it is not exceeded.

Comment: Ok, I thought the cutoff frequency should be lower if the voltage increases. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: A small addendum: you can notice this half supply bias as it is generated via R2/R3/C3, and fed to the non inverting pin of the amp through R4. C4 has a similar role as C5, it decouples the input - nonetheless you will find the DC bias of pin 1 directly on the amp output.

Answer (score 5):

It blocks the DC voltage from the speaker and it must be large because if forms a highpass filter together with the speaker impedance, which is usually pretty low like 8 Ohm.

Therefore, this capacitor is usually at least a few 100 uF large and is implemented as an electrolytic capacitor. This works if the amplifier output has a deterministic DC bias, such as in this case, where the amplifier has a single sided supply voltage range.

Answer (score 3):

> *I think it's here to avoid having DC voltage in the speakers when
> switching on the amplifier but, I'm not sure. If anyone could let me
> know on this, that would be great.*

Yes, that's what it is for - to avoid massive and unneeded DC currents flowing into the speaker which would lead to speaker damage and amplifier damage and possibly blown fuses (even though the LM1875 does have over-current protection).

Comment: but not only when the amplifier gets turned on, but all the time – the thing is simply AC-coupled.